# Autofilter inconsistency: method of range class failed

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

The following loop is working like a charm on one data set but on another data set with the same fields it is not working and giving me an error. I am at my wits end. Any debugging guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
For Each Itm In Array("SCL_FL", "FSL_SCL_FX")
                Workbooks(Original_Name).Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Workbooks.Add
                ActiveSheet.Name = Itm
                Sheets(Itm).Paste
                    If Itm = "SCL_FL" Then
                        Worksheets(Itm).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=SCL_FL"
                    Else
                        Worksheets(Itm).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("FSL", "SCL_FX"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    End If

Next Itm
```

I get the error "autofilter method of range class failed"

I get the same error when I do

```
Worksheets(Itm).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="SCL_FL", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Why is this line working on one data but not working on another data? Both data are actually the same. Just copied and pasted into different files with different file names.

Comment: Can you debug and check what is the value of `Debug.Print Worksheets(Itm).UsedRange.Address` at the time of error?

Comment: Also what is the value of `Itm` at the time of error.

Comment: @SiddharthRout  Itm="SCL_FL" . I don't know how to do the debug.print.. should I add that line in the loop?

Comment: Yes. Add `Debug.print itm` after `Sheets(Itm).Paste` and `Debug.Print Worksheets(Itm).UsedRange.Address` twice. In `IF` and `Else`

Comment: @SiddharthRout    I did ctrlG and the box below says SCL_FL
$A$1

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just notices that the file where my code works, the rows start from 1 (header) and from row 2 on it's data. But the original file that my boss gave me starts with 1 (header) and immediately after row 1 is row 22 and row 22 onwards data. I don't know if there are hidden rows or deleted rows or if this has anything to do with anything.

Comment: `@SiddharthRout I did ctrlG and the box below says SCL_FL $A$1 – Amatya 4 mins ago` if `Debug.Print Worksheets(Itm).UsedRange.Address` gives just `$A$1`, then we have a problem :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout can/should we take this to chat? Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are adding a workbook after the `Sheet1.Copy` command. The copy command already creates a new workbook. If you again add a new workbook after that, naturally the `usedrange` will give you `$A$1` as mentioned in the comments above.

Change your code to this and it will work.

```
Sub Run1Nov24()
    '
    '~~>Rest of your code
    '
    Dim itm
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each itm In Array("SCL_FL", "FSL_SCL_FX")
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add

        Workbooks(Original_Name).Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

        With ws
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Name = itm
            If itm = "SCL_FL" Then
                .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=SCL_FL"
            Else
                .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("FSL", "SCL_FX"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End If
         End With
      Next itm
    '
    '~~>Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)